# Meaning of average mark

Tags: statistics

What does the average mark tell you about an exam, for example??

For example, if the average mark is 70, does this mean that most of yhe students got a mark around 70?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. For example pair the students, in each pair we can have it that one student got 100 and the other got 40. The class avarage would be 70 but that doesn't reflect much about the class.

In general, the avarage of a list id numbers does not say a lot, the question is about how much is the variance between the numbers: If you know that the numbers are close (eg low variance) then the numbers are close, in some sence to their avarage. But that is a big if - for example 1000 are in a room with an avarage monthly salery of 100000 dollars. Does that say something about the 1000 individuals? What if 999 does not work, but one is Bill gates..

Answer (score 0):

It means that the sum of scores divided by the number of students is equal to 70.

Examples: 71, 69 -> average is 70

100, 40 -> average is also 70

Answer (score 0):

An average test score is the sum of all the scores on an assessment divided by the number of test-takers. For example, if three students took a test and received scores of 69, 87, and 92, these numbers would be added together and then divided by three to get an average of 82.6.